# Photos: reduce iCloud storage usage, keep old photos offline

Tags: icloud, photos.app

OS X 10.10.3 is released with an all-new Photos app. On launching Photos, it asks me if I want to enable iCloud Photo. I already use it on my iPhone / iPad, so off course. The next question is which storage plan I would like, as the 85 GB of iPhoto library won't fit my 20 GB plan. However I'm fine with my current plan and I don't wish to upgrade. I'm fine with not having all my photos and videos available on all my devices. However I would like to have my recent photo's synched between my devices. How can I achieve this?